# Copy paste file from home to public_html

Tags: centos, sudo, apache-httpd, webserver

[image]
Anyway to make this go away? I have asked in freenode #linux but I got roasted with such Karen comments as "Why on God's name earth would you do that?".  So yeah I just don't know.  Been stuck on this one for month.

Comment: What are the permissions of the **pictures** directory?

Comment: -rw-rw-rw- of the file

Comment: Which user is trying to make the move, which user owns the folder /var/.../pictures?
User which is trying to move the file needs to have write permission on the /var/.../pictures folder, and execute permission on all directories above it.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to move a file to a folder you need to have write permission to that folder. 
In order to be able to get to some folder you need to have execute permission on the folders above it, in its path. 
Write permission on the folder gives you permission to create new object in it (files or folders). 
Execute permission on the folder gives you permission to enter the folder (which is needed to be able to come to its subfolders, to write in them).

In order to be able to move file `taoismtreeofknowledge.jpg` to `/var/www/thepowerhouremethord.org/public_html/pictures` the user which is moving the file needs to have write permission on `/var/www/thepowerhouremethord.org/public_html/pictures` and execute permission and all the folders in its path.